# Google Maps v3 API - Auto Complete (address)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

Attempting to get auto complete working for my google maps application.

Here is the current code:

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="clearText" id="address" name="address" value="" size=20 autocomplete="off">
```

Javascript

```
    var input = document.getElementById('address');
    var options = {
        componentRestrictions: {country: 'au'}
    };
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

Unfortunately nothing happens when typing an address.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I'm actually receiving the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'autocomplete' of undefined

Not sure why, the code is placed in my map initialize function.

Edit 2: Fixed. Answer below.

Comment: Did you only load this script `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fixed. The autocomplete library is actually a separate library that must be explicitly loaded. The following line solved the problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places‌​&sensor=false"></scr‌​ipt>
```

Answer (score 21):

Your fix worked for me too.  I'm using the Geocomplete jQuery Plug-in http://ubilabs.github.com/geocomplete/
and the instructions on their home page says to use this

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script>
```

But it didn't work for me and was getting the same error.

See documentation for Google Maps API here
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places?hl=en-EN#loading_the_library

Comment: Strange it'd be interesting to know why this happens. Maybe the issue is due to the way the amperstand is being sent to the browser. Were you using PHP or html to generate the script? What browser?

Comment: This was a while ago but I think i was using a Rails erb template to generate the script.  So, HTML.

Comment: That wasn't working because the url should be `sensor=false&libraries=places` not `sensor=false&amp;libraries=places` which is what you had. `&amp;` is a html ampersand, not a URL one (because in a url it's just `&`) :).

Answer (score 9):

Since this question helped me I figured I would help anyonewho is having this problem in 2019.
In 2019 you add the google maps api import like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURAPIKEY
```

Then add &libraries=places to the end so that all said and done it looks like this:

```
<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURAPIKEY&libraries=places">
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

if you are using angular app:

If you are using google maps you have to import the Api in the ngmodule like this

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      clientId: '<mandatory>',
      //apiVersion: 'xxx', // optional
      //channel: 'yyy', // optional
      //apiKey: 'zzz', // optional
      language: 'en',
      libraries: ['geometry', 'places']
    })
  ],
  providers: [...],
  bootstrap: [...]
})
```

the library 'places' is needed to use the autocomplete module.

Than use it like this:

```
import {MapsAPILoader} from "@agm/core";
...
constructor(private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader,
...
    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      let autocomplete = new window['google'].maps.places.Autocomplete(..., ...);

      autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add 'defer async' to the script attribute, like this:

```
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
            async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Matt for the answer! Somehow it seems to be important not to omit `type="text/javascript"` attribute on `<script>` tag when using `libraries=places`.

Doesn't work:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libaries=places&sensor=false&callback=initMap"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libaries=places&sensor=false"></script>
```

Works:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
```

Callback variant also works (with initMap function defined):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false&callback=initMap"></script>
```

This seems to be consistent with another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18905094/4955259) and inconsistent with the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) (unless providing the `key` in the url makes the difference).

Answer (score 0):

i found this error because of my API key have exceeded daily request quota for this API.

i just create new API key and Replace it instead of old one.

it works for me

thank you

Answer (score 0):

In my case issue was resolve by changing the Libraries=places to libraries=places it seems to be case sensitive