# google.maps.places and its Autocomplete method are undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm loading the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/), [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and this [Geocomplete](http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/) plugin.
Please note that I'm also specifying the libraries (*libraries=places*) and eventually my *API key*:

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&amp;libraries=places&key=xxx'></script>
<script src='js/vendor/jquery.geocomplete.js'></script>
```

I'm triggering the Geocomplete plugin on the page load

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#my-input').geocomplete();
});
```

but I always get an error:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined [jquery.geocomplete.js:153]*.

Inside the plugin...

```
this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
 this.input, options
);
```

I tried to *google.maps* and it returns a regular object, but places is *undefined*!

Answer (score 80, accepted):

> I tried to google.maps and it returns a regular object, but places is undefined!

That means the google.maps.places library is not loading (the line of code that you posted, shown below is either not correct or is not actually on your page):

```
<script src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&amp;libraries=places&key=xxx'></script>
```

This is the example from the documentation:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
```

The only obvious difference is the `&amp;` in yours, that should work, but you should probably use it consistently.

**TL;DR**

Use `&libraries` not `&amp;libraries` and it will work.