# How to change marker postion on google map?

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-maps

I have a google map with marker and a select with options containing places.When the user selects an option lattitude and longitude are loaded from ajax success request and finally the marker on the google map must change position.

this is the script of the map:

```
function initSubmitMap(_latitude,_longitude){
         var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(_latitude,_longitude);
         var mapOptions = {
             zoom: 7,
             scrollwheel: false,
             center: mapCenter,
             disableDefaultUI: false,
             //scrollwheel: false,
             styles: mapStyles
         };
         var mapElement = document.getElementById('submit-map');
         var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
         var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
             position: mapCenter,
             map: map,
             icon: 'assets/images/marker.png',
             labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(50, 0),
             draggable: true
         });
         $('#submit-map').removeClass('fade-map');
         google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseup", function (event) {
             var latitude = this.position.lat();
             var longitude = this.position.lng();
             $('#latitude').val( this.position.lat() );
             $('#longitude').val( this.position.lng() );
         });
         /*google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);*/
          //Autocomplete
         var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */( document.getElementById('address-map') );
         var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
         autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
         google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
             var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
             if (!place.geometry) {
                 return;
             }
             if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                 map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
             } else {
                 map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                 map.setZoom(17);
             }
             marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
             marker.setVisible(true);
             $('#latitude').val( marker.getPosition().lat() );
             $('#longitude').val( marker.getPosition().lng() );
             var address = '';
             if (place.address_components) {
                 address = [
                     (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                     (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                     (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
                 ].join(' ');
             }
         });

    }
    function newLocation(newLat,newLng)
    {
        map.setCenter({
            lat : newLat,
            lng : newLng
        });
    }
```

and this is the script for the ajax request :

```
 $('select[name=governorat_id]').mouseup(function() { 
        var id = $(this).val(); 
         $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: "{{ URL::to('claim-gov-pos') }}",
            data: {
                'id': id
            },
            success:function(data){
                $("#latitude").val(data.lat);
                $("#longitude").val(data.lon);
                newLocation(parseFloat(data.lat),parseFloat(data.lon))
            }
        });
    });
```

i get the error map is not defined in the function newLocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your scoping of the map.

In your init function, you define your map as a local variable and therefore is only available in the scope of that function.

When you call it from newLocation - the variable is no longer defined.

Take a look at: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/es6/es6_variables.htm

However for a quick fix, without using ES6 syntax (let/const etc) or redesign, just globally declare `map` like below, I've also added some comments, you should try and catch errors and deal with them - like a try catch, or undefined/null checks, just a thought!

```
    var map, marker;
    function initSubmitMap(_latitude,_longitude){
             var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(_latitude,_longitude);
             var mapOptions = {
                 zoom: 7,
                 scrollwheel: false,
                 center: mapCenter,
                 disableDefaultUI: false,
                 //scrollwheel: false,
                 styles: mapStyles
             };
             var mapElement = document.getElementById('submit-map');
             //this part does not declare a local variable.
             map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
             marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                 position: mapCenter,
                 map: map,
                 icon: 'assets/images/marker.png',
                 labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(50, 0),
                 draggable: true
             });
             $('#submit-map').removeClass('fade-map');
             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseup", function (event) {
                 var latitude = this.position.lat();
                 var longitude = this.position.lng();
                 $('#latitude').val( this.position.lat() );
                 $('#longitude').val( this.position.lng() );
             });
             /*google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);*/
              //Autocomplete
             var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */( document.getElementById('address-map') );
             var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
             autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
             google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
                 var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                 if (!place.geometry) {
                     return;
                 }
                 if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                     map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
                 } else {
                     map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                     map.setZoom(17);
                 }
                 marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
                 marker.setVisible(true);
                 $('#latitude').val( marker.getPosition().lat() );
                 $('#longitude').val( marker.getPosition().lng() );
                 var address = '';
                 if (place.address_components) {
                     address = [
                         (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                         (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                         (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
                     ].join(' ');
                 }
             });

        }

        function newLocation(newLat,newLng) {
            //check map is not defined, try catch or null check???
            map.setCenter({
                lat : newLat,
                lng : newLng
            });
        }
```

In terms of the autocomplete:

[Google Maps v3 API - Auto Complete (address)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927849/google-maps-v3-api-auto-complete-address)

Comment: my problem is solved but i get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined" is there a way to solve it ?

Comment: @YoussefBoudaya - I've updated my answer with a link to a SO post regarding autocomplete